# question in MFC when drawing

Tags: c++, mfc

i want to move a picture which was drawed by me and rub the original.how can i do?

Comment: How did you draw the picture? You need to clear the old one and redraw it at the new coordinates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution for this is to keep the original picture in a [memory DC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwxzck32%28VS.80%29.aspx). Draw the image to it, then BitBlt it to the screen. When you want to move it, erase your window and BitBlt it again - now at the new location.

Comment: Ok,like your idea if i can draw and keep it in doc? which is faster?Another question ,i draw a picture and i want it can stretch every position.how can i do?

Comment: Yes, draw it once in the meoryDC and keep that. This is quite fast. If you use `StretchBlt` instead of `BitBlt`, you can stretch the picture when you copy it from the memory DC to the screen.